# Understanding C# untity "var del = ( Func<GameObject, MonoBehaviour>)" syntax

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Somebody please explain what the last three lines of code in following function means.

```
 public static void AddAssemblyToObject(Assembly assembly, string className, GameObject gameObj)
    {

        Type scriptClass = assembly.GetType(className);
        MethodInfo scriptFunc = scriptClass.GetMethod("AddScriptToComponent");

        //i dont understand what this is and how i can simplify it

        var del = (Func<GameObject, MonoBehaviour>)
        System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<GameObject, MonoBehaviour>), scriptFunc);


        MonoBehaviour addComponent = del.Invoke(gameObj);

    }
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/53cz7sc6(v=vs.110).aspx)? You may find useful information.

Comment: @Hellium Why link to a french resource?

Comment: Because he is french and the URL is defaulted to his culture.

Comment: It creates a delegate and invokes it. A delegate is a object that stores information that constitutes a method and its host (an instance of a type or simply the type). That is, a delegate has all the things you need except arguments to execute a method.

Comment: It's using reflection to create a delegate. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-hook-up-a-delegate-using-reflection

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Haha, my bad ! PatrickHofman is right! [Here is the english link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53cz7sc6(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I did read the Doc and did understand what a delagate does. I just did not fully understand the assignment to to var del and the call in the last line. Now it is clear to me  :) Thank you all for response.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly, You can imagine a `delegate` as some **variable**, under which You will find **a method** (not a value).

```
var del = (Func<GameObject, MonoBehaviour>)
System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<GameObject, MonoBehaviour>), scriptFunc);
```

First You call method to create a delegate:

```
System.Delegate.CreateDelegate();
```

Parameters:

```
// 1.
// calling typeof() method, which returns type of object

typeof( 
    Func<GameObject, MonoBehaviour>
)


// 2.
// variable, that stored information about some method/aplication code
scriptFunc
```

From the code above You are creating a delegate ("pointer to a code") based on the type and method name.

```
MonoBehaviour addComponent = del.Invoke(gameObj);
```

The last line invokes "the code" we are pointing at, returning the result (storing at `addComponent` variable).

---

Going around, if would have easy access to the method, You would simply do (would be equal as above):

```
MonoBehaviour addComponent = AddScriptToComponent();
```

The reason is You cannot reach the method simply, so You need to use reflection and delegates.

Comment: Something worth noting is that you don't really need to create a delegate to invoke a method via reflection. You can directly invoke a method with a `MethodInfo` object. (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx) IMHO creating a delegate is usually for better efficiency, as doing so binds the method info to a specific invoking instance and makes it strongly typed.